# Javascript Scope with Var

Tags: javascript

I am confused what the difference is between mine and the 'correct way'. I get my way is wrong scope but how did it result the way it did? I am not understanding how the result came out.

Here is the function:

```
convertObjectToList({
    name: 'Holly',
    age: 35,
    role: 'producer'
});
```

Desired answer: `[['name', 'Holly'], ['age', 35], ['role', 'producer']]`

My way:

```
function convertObjectToList(obj) {
    var brackOut = [];
    var brackIn = [];

    for (let key in obj) {
        brackIn.push(key);
        brackIn.push(obj[key]);
        brackOut.push(brackIn);
    }

    return brackOut;
}

convertObjectToList({
    name: 'Holly',
    age: 35,
    role: 'producer'
});
```

Result:

```
[ [ 'name', 'Holly', 'age', 35, 'role', 'producer' ],
  [ 'name', 'Holly', 'age', 35, 'role', 'producer' ],
  [ 'name', 'Holly', 'age', 35, 'role', 'producer' ] ]
```

vs.

The 'correct way':

```
function convertObjectToList(obj) {
    var brackOut = [];

    for (let key in obj) {
        var brackIn = [];

        brackIn.push(key);
        brackIn.push(obj[key]);
        brackOut.push(brackIn);
    }

    return brackOut;
}

convertObjectToList({
    name: 'Holly',
    age: 35,
    role: 'producer'
})
```

Result: `[ [ 'name', 'Holly' ], [ 'age', 35 ], [ 'role', 'producer' ] ]`

It has to do with the scope of variable, but can someone explain how my answer got that way? How does this work?

Answer (score 2):

Actually `brackIn` has the same scope in both cases¹. What matters is that you assign a new array to `brackIn` inside of the loop:

```
 var brackIn;

 for(let key in obj) {
   brackIn = []; // <<< !!!
   //...
 }
```

In the "wrong version", you always push to the same array and you also push that array to `brackOut` on every iteration (pushing the array won't clone it, JS has [call by sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)).

¹: Cause `var` is always scoped to functions (so your code is equal to the excerpt above). If you'd use `let` you would scope the variable locally to the loop.